# Issue with Projection in MongoDB C# Driver Using $facet Stage

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, projection

**Background:**

I'm working with the MongoDB C# driver and facing a projection issue when using the `$facet` stage in an aggregation pipeline. The projection works as expected in a simple scenario but fails to apply the same logic within the `$facet` stage.

**Problem:**

I have a `CustomerMail` field in my Order collection. I want to set it to a fallback value when it's null. The projection works correctly in a basic scenario but fails when using a more complex query with the `$facet` stage.

First of all, this is how I call the methods below:

```cs
await Repository.Query(_ => true, new List<SortExpression<Order>>(), x => new AdminOrderModel
                {
                    CustomerMail = x.CustomerMail ?? "fallback",
                    OrderDate = x.OrderDate,
                    State = x.State.ToString(),
                    Id = x.Id,
                    OrderName = x.OrderName,
                },
                1, 10, CancellationToken.None)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Working Scenario:**

Here's the code for the working scenario:

```cs
public async Task<PagedList<T>> Query<T>(
    Expression<Func<Order, bool>> filterExpression,
    IList<SortExpression<Order>> sortExpressions,
    Expression<Func<Order, T>> projectionExpression,
    int pageNumber,
    int pageSize,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var filter = Builders<Order>.Filter.Where(filterExpression);
    var sort = sortExpressions.IsNullOrEmpty() ? null : Builders<Order>.Sort.Combine(sortExpressions.Select(x => x.ToSortDefinition()));
    var projection = Builders<Order>.Projection.Expression(projectionExpression);
    var projectionDefinition = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Project(projection);

    var x = await _collection
        .Aggregate()
        .Match(filter)
        .AppendStage(projectionDefinition)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Additional implementation...
}
```

Here, `CustomerMail` is correctly set to "fallback" when it's null.

**Non-Working Scenario with $facet:**

However, when I use a similar projection within a $facet stage in an `AggregateByPageAsync` method, the fallback for `CustomerMail` doesn't get applied.

```cs
public async Task<PagedList<T>> Query<T>(
        Expression<Func<Order, bool>> filterExpression,
        IList<SortExpression<Order>> sortExpressions,
        Expression<Func<Order, T>> projectionExpression,
        int pageNumber,
        int pageSize,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var filter = Builders<Order>.Filter.Where(filterExpression);
        var sort = sortExpressions.IsNullOrEmpty()
            ? null
            : Builders<Order>.Sort.Combine(sortExpressions.Select(x => x.ToSortDefinition()));
        var projection = Builders<Order>.Projection.Expression(projectionExpression);
        var projectionDefinition = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Project(projection);

        var countFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("count",
            PipelineDefinition<Order, AggregateCountResult>.Create(new[]
            {
                PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Count<Order>(),
            }));

        var dataFacetPipelineStages = new List<IPipelineStageDefinition>
        {
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Skip<Order>((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize),
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Limit<Order>(pageSize),
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Project(projection),
        };
        if (sort != null)
        {
            dataFacetPipelineStages.Insert(0, PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Sort(sort));
        }

        var dataFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("data",
            PipelineDefinition<Order, AdminOrderModel>.Create(dataFacetPipelineStages));

        var aggregation = await _collection.Aggregate()
            .Match(filter)
            .Facet(countFacet, dataFacet)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

In this scenario, CustomerMail is not set to "fallback" when it's null within the `$facet` stage.

I tried to profile the queries in mongodb and weirdly enough the projection part is exactly the same in both queries:

```json
        '$project': {
          _id: 1,
          customerMail: 1,
          orderDate: 1,
          orderName: 1,
          state: 1
        }
```

**Question**

Why does the projection not apply the fallback value for CustomerMail when used within a $facet stage? Is there a different way to handle null values in projections within $facet?